# Assigning values to a new column based on a condition between two dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. I need to add the value of one column to every row in the other dataframe where the values of a particular column meet a condition from the first dataframe.

df1:

```
a b   
x 23  
s 34 
v 15 
g 05 
k 69
```

df2:

```
x y z
1 0 10
2 10 20
3 20 30
4 30 40
5 40 50
6 50 60
7 60 70
```

Desired output:

```
a b n
x 23 3 
s 34 4
v 15 2
g 05 1
k 69 7
```

In my dataset the intervals are large, and it's unlikely that a value from df1 is exactly on the boundary of a df2 interval.

Essentially for every row in `df1` I need to assign the number which corresponds to which range it fits into in `df2`. So if `df1$b` is between `df2$y` and `df2$z`, then assign the value of output$n as the corresponding value of `df2$x`. This is quite a wordy question, so please ask if I need to clarify.

Comment: I noticed that the ranges `y-z` in `df2` have no overlap. Is that the case with your dataset?

Comment: In my data they do not overlap, but they end on the same value. For example:
    0-10
    10-20
    20-30. The intervals are large in my data, and it's extremely unlikely that any of the values in the first df will hit exactly on a interval boundary

Comment: Cool. Always try to post an example as representative as possible. That will minimise the likelihood of getting a solution with bugs (when applied to your real dataset). :-)

Comment: I've updated it to be more representative of my datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
a b   
x 23  
s 34 
v 15 
g 05 
k 69
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 = read.table(text = "
x y z
1 0 10
2 10 20
3 20 30
4 30 40
5 40 50
6 50 60
7 60 70 
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

# function
f = function(x) min(which(x >= df2$y & x <= df2$z))
f = Vectorize(f)

# apply function
df1$n = f(df1$b)

# check updated dataset
df1

#   a  b n
# 1 x 23 3
# 2 s 34 4
# 3 v 15 2
# 4 g  5 1
# 5 k 69 7
```

Comment: Thank you! All the other solutions failed but this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(n=df2[ b > df2$y & b <= df2$z,1]) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      a     b     n
  <chr> <int> <int>
1     x    23     3
2     s    34     4
3     v    15     2
4     g     5     1
5     k    69     7
```

as already commented you have to change `<` or `>` to `<=` or `>=` accordingly to your needs.